# Is DynamoDB sorting impossible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I connected DynamoDB with Spring-boot.

Normal findAll() is work.
Pageable is work too.

But when I insert sort value, it's not a work.
And I tried to use findAllByOrderByBn() method.

This is my table information.
Partition key(hash key) is id.
Sort key(range key) is bn.

How can I sort?

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "tableName")
public class EntityName implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute private String bn;
    @DynamoDBAttribute private String fr;      // from
    @DynamoDBAttribute private String to;      // to

}



@EnableScan
@EnableScanCount
//public interface RepositoryName extends CrudRepository<EntityName, String> {
public interface EthereumTransactionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityName, String> {

    /* Find */
    Page<EntityName> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<EntityName> findByFrAndToBeforeOrderByBnDesc(String fr, String to, Pageable pageable);

}
```

If you need more code, reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are trying to sort based on range key, set the sort key. Annotation for the sort key is @DynamoDBRangeKey. So change the class to below

public class EntityName implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
private String id;

@DynamoDBRangeKey private String bn;
@DynamoDBAttribute private String fr;      // from
@DynamoDBAttribute private String to;      // to
```

And also if you want to sort in ascending or descending, you can refer to following documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#withScanIndexForward-boolean-